# Mysql selecting selecting from two tables for comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched the other related threads, but I don't think I'm looking for a UNION or an OUTER JOIN.  What I'm trying to do is pretty simple in theory.  I have two tables in two different databases, both with roughly the same data.  I'm trying to present them together so that we can compare them.  The field names are different, but the data is very similar.

Imagine something like this:

table 'foo':

```
 id  first_name  last_name      dept_name
+---+----------+---------------+-------------+
|  1|Bob       |Boberson       | Accounting  |
|  2|Steven    |McStevens      | Sales       |
|  3|Jane      |Janeston       | Support     |
+---+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

table 'bar':

```
 person_id  first      last            department_id
+----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|         1|Bob       |Boberson       |             2|
|         2|Doug      |Dugger         |             5|
|         3|Jane      |Janeston       |             3|
+----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

and I'm trying to end up with something like this:

```
 person_id  first      last            department
+----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|     foo_1|Bob       |Boberson       | Accounting   |
|     foo_2|Steven    |McStevens      | Sales        |
|     foo_3|Jane      |Janeston       | Support      |
|     bar_1|Bob       |Boberson       | Accounting   |
|     bar_2|Doug      |Dugger         | IT           |
|     bar_3|Jane      |Janeston       | Support      |
+----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

It's easy enough to get the two tables to resemble each other with two separate selects using 'as' to change the column names, concat's for various fields, and doing the appropriate join to fill in the 'department' fields.  But, I can't do a 'join' and keep that logic in place.  I really need to do a select statement for each table.  There's probably a simple solution here, but I'm not seeing it.

EDIT: You guys are correct, this is a pretty standard case for a UNION.  I was thinking that UNIONS always add columns for some reason.  Thanks.

Comment: So you dont want to join / trim duplicates from each table? Then you want a `UNION`?

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right.  I was thinking a UNION would create more columns.  I probably didn't do my homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `UNION` if you don't want to trim any duplicate names out then that will get data from both tables in 1 query, you can get the table name as part of your query to prefix the person_id if you want

This needs testing/improving but:

```
(SELECT foo AS table, f.id AS person_id, f.first_name AS first, f.last_name AS last, f.dept_name FROM foo AS f)
UNION
(SELECT bar AS table, b.person_id, b.first, b.last, FROM bar AS b)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks exactly like a UNION

Have a look as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0443f/10), I didn't bother doing a lookup for dept ID, but this should give you the basic idea.